# how to divide a shapefile and its data into tiles?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a population map of counties shapefile. I need to divide this data into tiles in order to have a gridded population map.

```
population_of_cell = population_of_county / area_of_county * area_of_cell
```

in grids intersecting two or more polygons, respecting the area share of each polygon, the population of cell is determined.
how can I divide so using QGIS?

[image: part of the map going to be gridded]

Comment: Does QGIS have an equivalent of Esri's "Create Fishnet" tool?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].